# proof verification in George J. Mailath and Andrew Postlewaite (2001b)

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, theory, matching

> [image]

I am reading George J. Mailath and Andrew Postlewaite (2001), and this is the lemma 1 in this paper. I don't understand the induction process in this proof. I think that we should use the fact that $x_{i+1} + p_{k+1}< v(b_{i+1}, s_{i+k})$ to show $x_{i+k-1}+p_{i+k} < v(b_{i+k-1}, s_{i+k})$.

At first, I did induction with respect to $k$. Since $k>1$, the first step of induction is $k=2$.  Then, we should show that $x_{i+1} + p_{i+2} < v(b_{i+1}, s_{i+2})$. But, I have no idea of how to show this.

Is my approach of induction correct? I appreciate if you give any help.  Please tell me if more context is needed.

Comment: Can you give the actual reference? 2001b is not informative and I'm pretty sure you are missing an author.

Comment: Here is the reference. Cole, H.L., Mailath, G.J. and Postlewaite, A., 2001. Efficient non-contractible investments in finite economies. Advances in Theoretical Economics, 1(1).